# Telescope on polluted environment

Tags: telescope

this one bothering me,to buy a telescope.
I live in a city,unfortunately with dust and polluted air, is there any affect in viewing a nice capture of our galaxy? Or i need to buy a special telescope?

Comment: I'd say you're (a) unlucky and (b) not in a great situation. Light pollution in the city will block out the best views - in fact, most views - in the sky.

Comment: @HDE226868,aw.thats sad. T.T

Answer (score 5):

If you are going to buy a telescope in the city let me suggest a large aperture and a reflective telescope.  I live in a city as well and I use a reflector telescope.  I did have trouble with some dimmer galaxies to start with but if you buy a light pollution filter you can see them a lot better.  Also take a series of images of the same object and then stack them together!  There are many free astronomy image stacking programs on the web.

Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

user3814836's answer seems to be right.

However, the choice of the telescope depends on what you want.

1. With a refractor telescope (I have one, a SkyWatcher BK 707AZ2). It's maybe a good start for a beginner, if you want to discover the brightest objects of the deep sky before going further. However, there is a defect: chromatic aberration. Also, you need to get used to the inversion of the image.
2. With a reflector telescope, you can see the dimmer objects. Maybe it will help if you have a lot of pollution.

As for the light pollution, the objects will look dimmer without an appropriate filter and you won't probably see the colours (personal experience with my telescope). The Moon doesn't help sometimes. If you have the chance to escape the pollution, you should be more amazed.